# How to get PageUp and PageDown to return to the exact same character?

Tags: cursor-movement

Because the default `Ctrl-B/F` or `PageUp/Down` behaviour usually leaves the cursor somewhere other than where it started, I remapped `PageUp` and `PageDown` in my `.vimrc` to simply move up/down 25 lines.

```
nnoremap <silent> <PageUp> 25<Up> 
nnoremap <silent> <PageDown> 25<Down>
```

But if I get to the top of the file the line number goes to 1 and so when I return down to near the original text it is now on the wrong line.

Is there some way to correct for this (perhaps some function for `PageUp` and `PageDown` that remembers when it could only go a lesser distance and so the first movement in the opposite direction also goes a lesser distance, or possibly some scheme where a marker is placed at the original spot... although I'd prefer not to have to remember to do that manually every time, just in case I may find myself needing it because I try to scroll too far).

I use Fedora 28 (but I'm pretty sure vi/vim under other systems had this problem of returning to a different line). `Ctrl-B/F` have the side effect of moving the cursor to the last/first line on the screen, so I often find the process of looking at something off the top of the screen means returning afterwards does not actually return me to the correct line; I have to hit up/down arrows a lot. And `PageUp/Down` keys are mapped to `Ctrl-B/F` so have this annoying feature. Using `Ctrl-U/D` or my simple workaround is usually better, except if I accidentally try to go too far... hence my question of a more general solution.

Comment: are you looking for `:set nostartofline`?

Comment: No, the cursor ends up on a totally different line after a set of matching `PageUp` and `PageDown` keystrokes even when the text on the screen returns to where it was (if the cursor began on one of the middle lines within the screen).  I presume this isn't unique to my particular Fedora implementation. It seems so annoying that I presume others have already found a solution to it, one better than my simple workaround that fails if I try to scroll too far.

Comment: What about this: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Page_up/down_and_keep_cursor_position

Answer (score 1):

You can mark the current position of the cursor typing `m` followed by an alphabet in normal mode which is the register to store it. If you use `ma` to mark it, you can jump back to this position by `` `a `` or `'a`. For more details, run `:help mark` in vim.

If you had used certain commands to navigate the documents, you can also have a look at `:help jump-motions` in vim.

As quoted there

> A "jump" is one of the following commands: "'", "`", "G", "/", "?", "n",
>   "N", "%", "(", ")", "[[", "]]", "{", "}", ":s", ":tag", "L", "M", "H" and
>   the commands that start editing a new file.  If you make the cursor "jump"
>   with one of these commands, the position of the cursor before the jump is
>   remembered.  You can return to that position with the "''" and "``" command,
>   unless the line containing that position was changed or deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Ctrl+O to go back to the previous positions instead of relying on the standard scrolling commands.

Answer (score 0):

```
" extracted from my ~/.vim/my/autoload/map/view.vim
" adapt to fit your need.

func! map#view#pagedown(cnt) abort
    let cnt = +a:cnt
    let info = getwininfo(win_getid(winnr()))[0]
    let height = info.height
    if cnt > 0
        if line('$') - info.topline < info.height
            norm! j
            return
        endif
        let off = line('.') - info.topline
        let pos = getcurpos()
        exec 'norm! H' . cnt . "\<C-f>"
        let pos[1] = line('.') + off
        call cursor(pos[1:])
    elseif cnt < 0
        let cnt = -cnt
        if info.topline == 1
            norm! k
            return
        endif
        let off = line('.') - info.topline
        let pos = getcurpos()
        exec 'norm! L' . cnt . "\<C-b>"
        let pos[1] = getwininfo(win_getid(winnr()))[0].topline + off
        call cursor(pos[1:])
    endif
endfunc

nn <silent> j :<C-u>call map#view#pagedown(v:count1)<CR>
nn <silent> k :<C-u>call map#view#pagedown(-v:count1)<CR>
```

Edit & Explanation:

Basically the what the function doing is,

- first save window info and cursor position into variable `pos`
- for `cnt > 0`, first switch to topline, then go pagedown cnt times
- for `cnt < 0`, first switch to botline, then go pageup cnt times
- then adust pos to intended line then `call cursor(pos[1:])`

In this fashion, you will always go down & up by exact page, which means after k, k, k, j, j, j you will stay at same row & col and difference of line('.') and the topline is the same, which mean you go back to exactly where you are.
That's much better/intuitive/consistent than default vim `<C-f>` & `<C-b>` or `<PageDown>` & `<PageUp>`.

Comment: An explanation would improve this answer. (And wow does it get my goat to see people write `cnt`, `func`, `nn` instead of spelling out the names.)